# How to set automatically meta tag from node content?

Tags: 6, meta-tags

I use the [Nodewords](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodewords) module and in the Readme file it talks about ability to automatically create metatag from node content but I don't find how to do.

> 5. Each content type should be configured to control whether certain meta tags
>      should be automatically generated, e.g. the "description" tag can be
>      automatically taken from the node teaser.

Do someone know? Do I need additional module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into your Drupal 6 backend and go to sitename.com/admin/content/types

Edit content type you wish to set auto generation of meta tags.

In this example I am editing Basic Page so I hit edit and ended up at

sitename.com/admin/content/node-type/page

Select "Meta tags settings" and on that page you can set various meta tag generation options.

One you probably want to set is:

- Generate meta tag content when the meta tag content is empty
  (default)

AND

- Generate meta tags content from the node teaser (default)

Both of these are default so they should be working out of the box.

Comment: great,thanks for explanation, do i wait for cache refreshing after modifying settings ? because actually no changes on a node type item example..

Comment: Depends on what kind of cache you have, if you have Boost or Varnish you will have to clear those out. You can always go to sitename.com/admin/settings/performance and clear Drupal cache from there.

Comment: yes i'm using boost.it works for description but not for keywords